# Putting multiline awk command in a for loop not printing the variable

Tags: loops, for-loop, awk

I have a command as follows, which takes lines from the **Allergens** file, based on lines from the **IDs** file.

```
awk '
    FNR==NR{
    a[$1]
    next
    }
    /^Query/ || $2 in a
    ' IDs C100_Allergens | grep -B 1 'Hit: ' | grep -v '^--'  > C100_Allergens_matches.txt
```

However, I have numerous **sample_Allergens** files, and want to run it in a loop as such, where **list** is a file with different sample names:

```
for i in `cat list`
do
    awk '
    FNR==NR{
    a[$1]
    next
    }
    /^Query/ || $2 in a
    ' IDs "$i"_Allergens | grep -B 1 'Hit: ' | grep -v '^--'  > "$i"_Allergens_matches.txt
done
```

I tried this loop, including using the variable flag for awk, i.e. -v i="$i":

```
for i in `cat list`
    do
        awk -v i="$i" '
        FNR==NR{
        a[$1]
        next
        }
        /^Query/ || $2 in a
        ' IDs "$i"_Allergens | grep -B 1 'Hit: ' | grep -v '^--'  > "$i"_Allergens_matches.txt
    done
```

I only keep getting empty files. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The idiom to select lines from the first file is `FNR==NR` (no `=` after the F). Your _awk_ script doesn't use any variable i for anything so setting `-vi=` is ineffective and useless.

Comment: Thanks @dave_thompson_085, that was a typo, and fixed now, i.e FNR==NR

Comment: Add some debugging prints to the shell and awk code to see where it's failing. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 for how to write your shell loop (assuming you really want to do that). Whatever it's supposed to do, piping your awk output to 2 greps and a 2nd pipe is the wrong approach.

Comment: Dear @EdMorton, thanks (yet again!) for your pointers. However, stating something is a 'wrong approach' rather than helping someone who seeks helps is a tad futile. Thanks on the other hand for the insights on how to write a shell loop.

Comment: I can't tell you the right way to do whatever it is you're trying to do because I don't know what it is you're trying to do. So I had 2 choices - 1) let you know it's a bad approach so you could investigate and/or ask a question after providing more information, or 2) not let you know it's a bad approach so you just keep doing it. Sorry to hear that doing 1 was futile.

Comment: Consider posting sample/subset files for the 'ID' files and for the 'Allergans' file that demonstrate the problem. hard to evaluate data-specific problem without any data.

Comment: Thanks @dash-o. The examples for the IDs, Allergens (File), and expected output are here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59986630/print-line-with-match-and-line-above-that-matches-another-pattern]

Comment: @SusheelBusi The files that were posted seems to work OK with the script. Consider narrowing the problem to MVRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - post one ID and one Allergan file that fail to work, so that SO readers will be able to reproduce the problem. Otherwise, it a search in the dark.